# Passive and Active Voice

Tags: passive-voice

I need to change this sentence to passive voice. Can you please help?

*What kind of music will he play now?

THANKS PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What kind of music will be played by him now?

Comment: Sentences of exercise books no one will ever need.